# Cannot resolve symbol after start of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

every time i start Android Studio (currently 2022.2.1 Patch 2) it cannot find my interfaces and classes from my external library.

I use gradle to build my application and i have the following entry in my build.gralde:

```
dependencies {
  implementation files('lib/myAPI.jar')
}
```

The strange thing is, after i rename the package path in my application (com.app -> com.appx -> com.app), all external interfaces and classes are successfully recognised. I have no problems with libraries being included in this way:

```
dependencies {
  implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what causes the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Unfortunally google showed nothing useful for my search parameters.